# MPMoviePlayerViewController vs. Appearance-Framework (iOS 5)

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, appearance

i am using a MPMoviePlayerViewController inside my Project. I have defined the following appearance for UIButtons and UINavigationbar like so:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem   appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]   
                    setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"woodenBarButton"] 
                    forState:UIControlStateNormal 
                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UINavigationBar appearance]   setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbarBackground"] 
                                forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

So now MPMoviePlayerViewController is also using a navigation bar. The problem is now: The button uses the given appearance but the toolbar not => it looks crappy. So now i have the following questions:

1. Can i convince the UINavigationBar in MPMoviePlayerViewController to use the appearance?
2. OR can is remove appearance completely only for the MPMoviePlayerViewController.

I tried to access the button via playerViewController.navigationitem.leftbarbuttonitem and overwrite properties but that doesn't work.

Would be great if you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: no one here who could help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tried also setting `appearanceWhenContainedIn` for `MPMoviePlayerViewController`? `appearance` and `appearanceWhenContainedIn` works both at the same time.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]   setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbarBackground"] 
                            forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: glad to be of help. please mark this answer as the correct answer (the checkmark) as it is common behavior on stackoverflow. thx

Comment: Used this technique to remove appearance customisations when presenting MFMessageComposeViewController also. thanks